# Installing vmware tools on a windows vm using ansible

Tags: ansible, vmware-tools

I am trying to install vmware tools on a guest vm using ansible. Most of the examples I have seen online have been on linux using open-vm-tools. This an example below.

```
    - name: debian | installing open-vm-tools
  apt: name=open-vm-tools state=present
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian" and ansible_virtualization_type == "VMware"

- name: centos | installing open-vm-tools if a vm
  yum: name=open-vm-tools state=present
  when: ansible_os_family == "Redhat" and ansible_virtualization_type == "VMware"

- name: centos | starting and enabling open-vm-tools
  service: name=vmtoolsd.service state=restarted enabled=yes
  when: ansible_os_family == "Redhat" and ansible_virtualization_type == "VMware"
```

Is there an example of how to do it in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest using [win_chocolatey](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_chocolatey_module.html) to automatically download and install, eg:

```
- name: install vmware tools via Chocolatey
  win_chocolatey: name="vmware-tools"
```

Otherwise, win_copy + win_package to push the package over and install it.